# R language: how to return and print a list of missing entries based on two columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm struggling to write R code that prints a **"list of dates that do not have data between given start and end dates for all the possible values of another variable / column in a table"**. It's a little difficult to explain in words, so I'll give a very simplified example that will hopefully make it clear what I'm trying to do.

> You are the manager of a pet store and in charge of checking the quality of pet food sales data. The data comes in a csv file with four columns; date, type of animal food, sales price, and quantity sold. The animal_type column can have **3 possible values; dog, cat, or bird in string format**.

> I've simulated the first three days worth of data for the month of December in a very simplified manner below. The price and quantity columns aren't relevant and so I've left them blank.

| date | animal_type | price | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-01 | dog |  |  |
| 2021-12-01 | dog |  |  |
| 2021-12-01 | cat |  |  |
| 2021-12-01 | bird |  |  |
| 2021-12-02 | dog |  |  |
| 2021-12-02 | bird |  |  |
| 2021-12-03 | cat |  |  |
| 2021-12-03 | cat |  |  |
| 2021-12-03 | cat |  |  |

**What I'm trying to do is print out / return the dates that don't have entries for all the possible values in the animal_type column**. So for my example, what I'm looking to print out is something like...

```
2021-12-02  :  ['cat']
2021-12-03  :  ['dog', 'bird']
```

Because [2021-12-02] doesn't have an entry for 'cat' and [2021-12-03] doesn't have entries for 'dog' or 'bird' in the data. However, I've only been able to get a count of the number of unique animal_type values for each date so far with the following functions.

```
import(tidyverse)
import(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(date) %>% summarise(n = n_distinct(unique(animal_type))) # sums the number of unique animal_type appearing in all the entries for every date
df %>% group_by(animal_type) %>% summarise(n = n_distinct(unique(date))) # sums the number of unique dates that appear in all the entries for every animal_type
```

```
# output for "sums the number of unique animal_type appearing in all the entries for every date"
   date            n
   <date>       <int>
1 2021-12-01       3
2 2021-12-02       2
3 2021-12-03       1

# output for "sums the number of unique dates that appear in all the entries for every animal_type"
  animal_type   num_dates
  <chr>         <int>
1 dog             2
2 cat             2
3 bird            2
```

This can me tell which dates have missing animal_type values but not which one(s) specifically. I've tried looking around but couldn't find many similar problems and so I'm wondering how feasible this would be. I'm also rusty with using R and relearning much of the syntax, packages, and libraries. So I could be missing something simple. I'm open to both tidyverse / dplyr and base r advice as you can likely see from my code. I would appreciate any help and thank you guys for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use both the tidyr::complete function and an anti-join.

First you have to complete the implicit missing values and then anti-join the completed tibble with the one you currently have.

See the example below

```
library(tidyverse)
example <- crossing("Date"=c("2021-12-01", "2021-12-02", "2021-12-03"), 
         "Pet"=c("Bird", "Cat", "Dog"))

op_example <- example %>% slice(-c(5, 7, 9))
op_example %>% complete(Date, Pet) %>% 
  anti_join(op_example)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried your solution and it worked. But I'm a little confused about what the `op_example <- example %>% slice(-c(5, 7, 9))` is doing though. Could you explain if possible?

Comment: I was just replicating the data you provided! You don't need to use that part. AS always feel free to upvote if the answer suits your needs.

Comment: Do you know of a way to generalize the role of the `op_example <- example %>% slice(-c(5, 7, 9))` part of the code? I've been playing around with your solution but I feel that using slice to manually cut out the missing entries is too specific to the example data. Because you already know what the missing entries vs. trying to find them. I would like see if I can find missing entries on other similar but larger datasets. I've tried using group_by() but the syntax doesn't play well with complete() and anti_join()

Comment: It doesn't matter. Even if the missing parts are random, the approach is the same. You use complete on the dataset with the columns that you want to find all combinations across. And then use that dataframe to antijoin against the original.